# Three nails vs three pieces of nail

Tags: nouns

which one is correct?

> 1.I have bought three nails. 
>   2.I have bought three pieces of nail.

is nail a material or common noun? 
arm a proper noun or common noun?

Answer (score 1):

We quantify mass nouns with certain words like 'pieces.' Say -

> Three pieces of furniture

Since we cannot say 'three furnitures,' the word 'pieces' is used to quantify it

Nevertheless, [*nail* word is countable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nail) and thus, I feel there is no need to quantify like that.

> I have bought three nails for the poster to hang.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is correct. Maybe you are confusing "nail" with "mail" - "mail" is a mass noun, but "nail" is not. A nail is a small sharp metal object that you hammer into the wall. You can count nails. Technically you could have a piece of nail, but I don't think this is what you meant here, and this is not the normal usage.